# How to make an accepted socket non-blocking in java

Tags: java, sockets, nonblocking

I'm accepting a connection from a client and then passing that connected socket off to another object, however, that socket needs to be non-blocking. I'm trying to use `getChannel().configureBlocking(false)` but that does not seem to be working. It needs to be non-blocking because this the method below is called every 100ms. Is there some other way that I should be making this non-blocking? Thanks for any help!

```
public void checkForClients() {
  DataOutputStream out;
  DataInputStream in;
  Socket connection;
  InetAddress tempIP;
  String IP;

  try {
     connection = serverSocket.accept();
     connection.getChannel().configureBlocking(false);

     System.err.println("after connection made");

     in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
     out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
     tempIP = connection.getInetAddress();
     IP = tempIP.toString();

     System.err.println("after ip string");

     // create a new user ex nihilo
     connectedUsers.add(new ConnectedUser(IP, null, connection, in, out));


     System.err.println("after add user");
  } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
     System.err.println("accept timeout - continuing execution");
  } catch (IOException e) {
     System.err.println("socket accept failed");
  }
}
```

Comment: This question is answered in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541804/creating-the-serversocket-in-a-separate-thread. The answer is to put the server socket in its own thread.

Answer (score 12):

Two things:

1. Why aren't you using a [`ServerSocket`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) if you're listening for connections?
2. If you want to accept multiple clients you want to use a loop.

The basic structure of a multi-client server is:

```
while (true) {
  // accept connections
  // spawn thread to deal with that connection
}
```

If the issue is blocking on the `accept()` call, well that's what `accept()` does: it blocks waiting for a connection. If that's an issue I suggest you have a separate thread to accept connections.

See [Writing the Server Side of a Socket](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html).

Comment: this does not answer the question, but that is in most cases the way to go - if you really want non blocking IO go with the nio package mentioned in the other answers (but that also means no streams!)

Comment: @rurouni There *isnt* an answer, as you can't do it without shifting over to NIO.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect your code to block on the accept call, never getting to the configureBlocking call.

I typically spin off a separate thread for each socket connection, and let it block until a connection is actually made/accepted  This allows the main thread to continue unblocked while it is waiting for client connections.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for non-blocking sokets, my suggestion is to use Selectors and ServerSocketChannels with the NIO package.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/nio/

Answer (score 0):

If the typical blocking socket doesn't give you the availability you need (a connection every 100ms does seem tight). You should look at a non-blocking socket. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/NbServerSocket.html). You can also look at Apache [MINA](http://mina.apache.org/features.html) to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use an I/O loop (event loop) in a single threaded environment. Take a look at [Deft web server](https://github.com/rschildmeijer/deft) for inspiration. (Especially the start() method in [IOLoop](http://github.com/rschildmeijer/deft/blob/master/src/main/java/org/deft/web/IOLoop.java))