# How to continuously listen on port with java.net.ServerSocket

Tags: java, network-programming, serversocket

I have a [java.net.ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) that is am using to listen for connections. I am using it's [accept()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) method in order to obtain connections from clients and then handle them appropriately. I wish to **continously** be listening for clients and never be unavailable to them. Currently I have code similar to this:

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = ...
while (shouldBeListening) {
    handleClient(serverSocket.accept());
}
```

The `handleClient` method may take a small amount of time (less than a tenth of a millisecond). I am worried that between the time the [ServerSocket.accept()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) method returns and it is called again that a request for a connection could have been missed. What is the best way to solve this issue?

EDIT:
The way I am implementing it currently creates a new thread in the `handleClient` method, but even this takes time (especially since this is being run on a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/)), I am worried that if a connection is requested while the `handleClient` method is being executed then it may be rejected because [accept()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) is not being run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this.

```
 ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8001);
    try {
      while (true) {
         Socket socket = listener.accept();
```

Then you can pass socket reference to the handler class you have. Make that class implements **Runnable**. Create a new thread each time you pass the socket reference to the handler class to handle the requests simultaneously.
Please see the below links for solutions. If you need a full code. Let me know.

[Runnable Sample by Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html)

[ThreadPool Sample -  Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15541804/creating-the-serversocket-in-a-separate-thread)

Comment: Wouldn't this have the same problem? If a connection comes in and the accept method is returned from, what if another connection comes in before the JVM has the chance to call the accept method a second time? Even if I offload all of the main work to another thread, I still have to create and start a thread, which takes time. During that time, I may have missed a connection.

Comment: Valid question. Then you will have to queue  the client requests. Or use a messaging service for accepting requests.

Comment: Please check  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/thread-pooled-server.html

Comment: Ok, the article suggests that it is not possible to always be accepting connections. It surprises me that there is not some way to always be listening for a connection, but I suppose I will just have to make sure clients retry connections in case the JVM was outside the accept method. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. If you need to implement continues listening mechanism , you will have to try a different java technology. However, it is better retrying if clients receive any connection related exceptions. Also make sure the sever handles duplicate requests.